# Multiple Windows in Extjs

Tags: extjs

I'm having a situation in Extjs where I have to display one window for 3 button clicks. Let me be clear, I have one window "A", that "A" window I have to show on click of Button 1, Button 2, Button 3. Is there any way to do this because of course, I'm getting the duplicate id error while I'm accessing the same window on Button 2 and Button 3 clicks. BTW I want to show all 3 windows on the page at a time.

Comment: Can you attach some example (eg. on sencha fiddle) ?

Comment: Use generic ID or don't use IDs at all.

Comment: Hi @norbeq,i got the solution.https://jsfiddle.net/sravs66/0pdb2nre/46/